# codeMirror within an extendable <td> doesn't seem to disappear/appear when a button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, codemirror

I am attempting to developing this system where you can edit code using the CodeMirror text area's and then the code is automatically run in an iframe.

On this system there will be a button that a lows the user to make the CSS textarea and the table column disappear. But for some reason I cant get it to work. Here is the code that I have got so far, as follows:

```html
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="mode/clike/clike.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="mode/xml/xml.js"><!-- needed for htmlmixed --></script>
<script src="mode/css/css.js"></script>
<link href="theme/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme/mdn-like.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>
    .CodeMirror {
        border:none;
        width:100%;
        height:451px;
        margin-left:100;
    }
</style>




 <table id="sample2" width="100%" height="500px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
   <tr>
               <td colspan="3"><button onClick="displayCSS()">Hide/Show CSS</button></td>
            <tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="left">
    
    <textarea id="code" name="code" style="padding-top:0px; border:none;" ><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
      
 </head>
 <body>
     
 </body>
</html>
</textarea> 
 <select style="height:46px; width:100%; margin:0px; position:relative; left:0%;">
  <option value="volvo">index.html</option>
  <option value="saab">another_page.html</option>
  <option value="mercedes">placeholder_page.html</option>
  <option value="audi">other.html</option>
</select>
<script> 
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "htmlmixed",
    lineWrapping: true,
    theme: 'default',
  });
</script>
    
    </td>
    
    <td>1</td><td></td>
    
 



 <td class="left" id="Column" class="hidden" style="position:relative; left:17px;">
    
    <textarea id="code2" name="code2" style="padding-top:0px; border:none; padding-left:300px;" >h2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

h2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

h2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

h2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</textarea> 
 <select style="height:46px; width:100%; margin:0px; position:relative; left:0%;">
  <option value="volvo">main.css</option>
  <option value="saab">main2.css</option>
  <option value="mercedes">main3.css</option>
  <option value="audi">other.css</option>
</select>
<script> 
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code2"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/css",
    lineWrapping: true,
    theme: 'default',
  });
</script>
    
    </td>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
   
  
<td class="right" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding:none; margin:none; border:none;">

<iframe src="http://duckduckgo.com" style="width:99%; height:100%; border:none; margin-left:13px;"></iframe>
   




</td>



</tr>
                   
</table>
```

I still need to make the code executed in the iFrame automatically, but for now I just want the user to be able to make the css textarea disappear and appear. Any help would be highly appreciated - thanks :)

Comment: Did you try the snippet I shared? You need to use: var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[1].CodeMirror; to access the second code mirror instance. Can you print in console and see what this returns?

Comment: Also, I suggest you use different variable names for both the editors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @GobSmack - I tried the code you provided me in the previous question, although it worked in other systems it didn't seem to work in this system. I am really confused at this point why it isn't working - I have spent a couple of days trying to figure it out haha. And I will change the variable names for both of the editors - I am just using them as placeholders for now :)

Comment: What is 'this system' ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean this site I am creating - with the screen shot of it above in the question

Comment: Try printing $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror; in your console. What does it print?

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't, that was my bad - it prints 'CodeMirror {options: Object, doc: C…r.Doc, display: Display, state: Object, curOp: null}'

Comment: Any idea whats going on? @GobSmack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed there were three errors. The displayCSS function wasn't defined at all.  You need to include jQuery. And the tr around the button isn't closed properly.

Here's the modified code:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="codemirror.js"></script>
<link href="../css/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="xml.js"><!-- needed for htmlmixed --></script>
<script src="css.js"></script>

<style>
    .CodeMirror {
        border:none;
        width:100%;
        height:451px;
        margin-left:100;
    }
</style>




 <table id="sample2" width="100%" height="500px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="3"><button onclick="displayCSS()">Hide/Show CSS</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <textarea id="code" name="code" style="padding-top:0px; border:none;" >
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>

                        </head>
                        <body>

                        </body>
                    </html>
                </textarea> 
                 <select style="height:46px; width:100%; margin:0px; position:relative; left:0%;">
                  <option value="volvo">index.html</option>
                  <option value="saab">another_page.html</option>
                  <option value="mercedes">placeholder_page.html</option>
                  <option value="audi">other.html</option>
                </select>
                <script> 
                  var editor1 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    matchBrackets: true,
                    mode: "htmlmixed",
                    lineWrapping: true,
                    theme: 'default',
                  });
                </script>   
            </td>

    <td class="left" id="Column" class="hidden" style="position:relative; left:17px;">
         <textarea id="code2" name="code2" style="padding-top:0px; border:none; padding-left:300px;" >
            h2 
            {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            h2 
            {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            h2 
            {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            h2 
            {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
         </textarea> 
         <select style="height:46px; width:100%; margin:0px; position:relative; left:0%;">
          <option value="volvo">main.css</option>
          <option value="saab">main2.css</option>
          <option value="mercedes">main3.css</option>
          <option value="audi">other.css</option>
        </select>
        <script> 
          var editor2 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code2"), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            matchBrackets: true,
            mode: "text/css",
            lineWrapping: true,
            theme: 'default',
          });
        </script>
    </td>               
    <td class="right" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding:none; margin:none; border:none;">
        <iframe src="http://duckduckgo.com" style="width:99%; height:100%; border:none; margin-left:13px;"></iframe>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>

<script>
function displayCSS()
{
    var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[1].CodeMirror;
    $(cm.getWrapperElement()).toggle();
}
</script>
```

**Edit**

http://jsfiddle.net/aLwjhp1w/1/

Comment: @GodSmack - I deleted the comment - Im sorry for being a pain but please can you send me the link to the fiddle

Comment: I have added it in the answer

Comment: Great! Thank you @GobSmack - you are a legend :)

Comment: Not a legend, just learnt things through practice! Always keep your console open and console.log is your best friend. Don't forget that :)